# Making information bubbles with css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have searched whole web world but nothing found. My problem is that we are trying to make bubbles and they have to look like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOsO8.png)

And when we click anyone it must show information about some data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fMOZ.png)

Could you help us please?

Comment: use `border-radius` , also make the element an `<a>` tag.

Comment: This is very, very broad for SO. Please try something first, then we can start from there. What can I advice is not tackle the problems all at once, do it one at a time, like for example, practice making a circle expand when clicked or something first.

Comment: @Swellar you are right. But i couldnt find any close information about that. I am backend developer and this is something very hard to find for css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with:

Use `border-radius` to have bubble and on click you just expand it's size.

Add some JS logic that will move other bubble when clicked.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.frame {
  position: relative;
}

.bubble {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(50, 90, 140, .3);
  padding-top: 55px;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  z-index: 6;
}

.bubble .content {
  display: none;
}

.bubble.active {
  width: 260px;
  height: 260px;
  z-index: 20;
}
.bubble.active .content {
  display: block;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

#b1 {
  top: 50px;
  left: 60px;
}

#b2 {
  top: 168px;
  left: 68px;
  background-color: rgba(150, 40, 90, .3);
}

#b3 {
  top: 168px;
  left: 68px;
  background-color: rgba(60, 200, 90, .3);
}

#b3 {
  top: 80px;
  left: 150px;
  background-color: rgba(200, 200, 40, .3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="frame">
  <div class="bubble" id="b1" onClick="$(this).toggleClass('active')">
    <span class="header">Random text</span><br>
    <div class="content">
      random text random text random text random text random text <br>
      random text random text random text random text 
      <br>
      random text random text random text 
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="bubble" id="b2" onClick="$(this).toggleClass('active')">
    <span class="header">Random text</span><br>
    <div class="content">
      random text random text random text random text random text <br>
      random text random text random text random text 
      <br>
      random text random text random text 
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="bubble" id="b3" onClick="$(this).toggleClass('active')">
    <span class="header">Random text</span><br>
    <div class="content">
      random text random text random text random text random text <br>
      random text random text random text random text 
      <br>
      random text random text random text 
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="bubble" id="b4" onClick="$(this).toggleClass('active')">
    <span class="header">Random text</span><br>
    <div class="content">
      random text random text random text random text random text <br>
      random text random text random text random text 
      <br>
      random text random text random text 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```